# How to play two videos simultaneously using GiraffePlayer in android activity

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, android-video-player

I have to play HD video using GiraffePlayer in Android version 4.2.2 and it plays perfectly,
but I have issues when I play two video than at the time only one video is playing when I play second video then it stops the first video.
So if anyone can idea about how to play two videos simultaneously using GiraffePlayer then let me know.

That's my code and libraries that I have used:

> compile 'com.github.tcking:giraffeplayer2:0.1.12'
>   compile 'com.github.tcking:ijkplayer-x86:0.8.4'

```
MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String url = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/720p.mp4";

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    videoView.setVideoPath(url).getPlayer().start();

    String url1 = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/360.mp4";

    VideoView videoView2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view2);
    videoView2.setVideoPath(url1).getPlayer().start();

}
}
activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.ic.lcd.MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <tcking.github.com.giraffeplayer2.VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="210dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <tcking.github.com.giraffeplayer2.VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot do that because of how `MediaPlayer` works internally... But bigger question is why do you want to do that?

Comment: i have to develop advertisement app with show multiple video ads show in one screen and that video is in HD format thats via i have to try to do this. and also one of the old app that are client used in our system right now with same features like show multiple ads in one screen.